# Start Chrome opening bookmarks in a folder

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to start chrome opening all the pages in a bookmark folder?.

I've looked through all the command-line options but can't find any option for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can launch all those bookmarks in a single-click when necessary. This gives better control in my opinion. Here is how:

**Navigate** to Bookmarked folder > **Popup** menu will appear > **Select** Open All Bookmarks

And if you must want to launch on startup then you can define **statically**, Here are two different ways:

1. Go to `chrome://chrome/settings/` > Under `On startup` > Choose Open a specific page or set of pages. Here you can specify URLs of pages that you want to automatically launch every time on startup.

[image]

2. Create a file with `.bat` extension > Add this code and save on Desktop

   ```
   start chrome "site1.com" "site2.com"
   ```

   Double click on file to launch

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply, it's not yet what I was looking for as what I want to do is opening a set of specific pages at certain moment from an external process. "Start chrome some-bookmark-folder1, some-bookmark-folder2" ... would be ideal.

Comment: well, you can define bookmarked sites **Statically** in a `bat` file and execute that from external process. Maybe this extension helps you: [Daily Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/daily-links/keepgbcgekdilbnpklfknmkfmehppaag)

Comment: Yes, I guess it will be a matter of either list all the sites in a command or extract the contents of the chrome's bookmarks, filter it and invoke chrome with the sites.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux create python script named `open_bookmarks.py`:

```python
import json
import os
    
    
BOOKMARKS_PATH = os.environ["HOME"] + "/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks"
BOOKMARKS_FOLDER_NAME = "Work bookmarks"
    
with open(BOOKMARKS_PATH, "r") as f:
    bookmarks = json.load(f)
    children = [] 
    for child in bookmarks["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"]:
    if child["name"] == BOOKMARKS_FOLDER_NAME:
        children = child["children"]
        break
    
urls = [child["url"] for child in children]
res = "google-chrome " + " ".join(urls)
print(res)
```

Then run script in bash console:

```bash
python3 open_bookmarks.py & disown
```